# Add plus/minus buttons to the zoom slider in the status bar in Word for Mac 2011

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

In Microsoft Word (for Windows) 2010 there are plus and minus buttons besides the zoom slider in the status bar (bottom right) that allow to zoom in/out by jumps of 10% rounded to the next 10%.

[image: [Link to Screenshot of Word Windows 2010](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42384796/ZoomSliderWindowsWord2010.png)]

Microsoft Word for Mac 2011 has the same slider but not those buttons. I find using the slider very difficult, the zoom jumps way to fast and a "fine-grained" zooming is not possible (on my laptop).

[image: [Link to Screenshot of Word for Mac 2011](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42384796/ZoomSliderMacWord2011.png)]

Does anybody know if I could get those buttons there and how?

As a workaround one can use <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-scroll up/down with a mouse or <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-two-finger-swipe up/down on a trackpad to zoom in and out.

Comment: As a workaround, there are probably menu items with zoom in/out functionality. Maybe it's also possible to click on the slider to focus it, then press arrow keys to move it.

Comment: There are workarounds (I added one into the question), but the arrow key trick doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best I can do is create VBA as below and assign to keystrokes and/or buttons. It doesn't give you buttons near the slider (a toolbar there would be a floating window and wouldn't move when you resized the main Window), but you can put a button either side of the Zoom dropdown in the Standard toolbar. Even to do that I had to

- create the macros (say, in Normal.dotm)
- go into View-Toolbars->Customize Toolbars and Menus...->Toolbars and
  Menus
- Click "New ..." for a new (temporary) toolbar. The default name is fine.
- Click the Commands tab in the dialog box
- Under Categories, select Macros
- Locate each macro in the list on the right and drag it to the new
  toolbar
- Right click on each new "button" (which will show the macro name) and

  - click Properties...
  - Select an icon from the dropdown at the top left (I used the arrows
    at the left of row 5)
  - In the View: dropdown, select "Default style"
- Then drag each arrow to the appropriate location in the Standard
  toolbar
- Delete the temporary toolbar

Word's event programming could clearly be improved because even then, when you change the zoom, the Zoom dropdown values do not update until you click in the document again (whereas the value on the slider at the bottom does update immediately).

The macro code...

```
Sub zoomIn10()
On Error Resume Next
With ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Zoom
  .Percentage = .Percentage + 10
End With
End Sub

Sub zoomOut10()
On Error Resume Next
With ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Zoom
  .Percentage = .Percentage - 10
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works for me. I added the step of creating a new (temporary) toolbar. Why can I not edit the looks of the button once it's in the standard toolbar..?

As for me, the zoom level updates immediately in both places (zoom pull down menu in standard toolbar as well as in the status bar).

While it's not exactly what I was looking for, this makes it still very easy to zoom in and out so I'm accepting your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Useful edits, thanks. I don't know why you can't edit the button appearance at that point, but if you put the button on the Formatting bar instead, you can change it as long as you undock the bar first, so that seems to be the deciding factor. You can't set the Standard bar to float via the U.I. AFAICS.

Answer (score 0):

Take the min/max zoom ratio into consideration (because the min zoom ratio is 10% and max 500%. The script makes sure it won't exceed both limits):

```
Sub Edit_ZoomIn()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim originalZoom As Integer 'variable for original zoom
    Dim targetZoom As Integer
    originalZoom = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage 'get current zoom
    targetZoom = originalZoom + 10
    If targetZoom > 500 Then
        targetZoom = 500
    End If
    ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage = targetZoom
End Sub

Sub Edit_ZoomOut()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim originalZoom As Integer 'variable for original zoom
    Dim targetZoom As Integer
    originalZoom = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage 'get current zoom
    targetZoom = originalZoom - 10
    If targetZoom < 10 Then
        targetZoom = 10
    End If
    ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage = targetZoom
End Sub

Sub Edit_Zoom0()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage = 100
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide more context to the code in your answer?